# Issue compiling program in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have successfully compiled/ran other programs but when I try to compile/run the code below, it tells me: "This project has not been built yet, do you want to build it now?".

When I take int b out of the function getWinnings() it will compile/run, though if I add more arguments code::blocks gives me the message above. What is causing this?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>

    int gameCoins;

    using namespace std;

    void instructions();
    void playSlots();
    void spin();

    int main()
    {
    srand(time(NULL));
    instructions();
    playSlots();
    }

    void instructions()
    {
    cout << "\t\t" << "VIRTUAL SLOT MACHINE" << "\n\n";
    cout << "INSTRUCTIONS: " << endl << "You start with 500 coins. The game is over either when you run out of coins or you quit the game." << "\n";
    cout << "It will cost you 25 coins per spin. Good luck!" << "\n\n" ;
    }
    void playSlots()
    {
    string user_input;
    string replay_or_quit;

    while (replay_or_quit != "n" && replay_or_quit != "no")
    {
    gameCoins = 500;
    cout << "Coins: " << gameCoins << "\n";
    while (user_input != "spin" && user_input != "Spin")
    {
        cout << "Spin the wheels to start playing. Type 'spin' to begin" << "\n";
        cin >> user_input; cout << "\n\n";
    }
    spin();
    while (gameCoins > 0 && user_input != "no" && user_input != "n")
    {
        cout << "Spin again?" << "\n" << "Decision: ";
        cin >> user_input;
        if (user_input == "y" || user_input == "yes")
        spin();
    }
    if (gameCoins == 0)
    {
        cout << "You went broke. Play again?" << "\n" << "Decision: ";
        cin >> replay_or_quit;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Congratulations, you won " << gameCoins << " coins. Play again?" << "\n" << "Decision: ";
        cin >> replay_or_quit;
    }
}
}

    int getWinnings(int a, int b)
    {
    return (a+b);
    }
    void spin()
    {
int wheelOne_Top, wheelOne_Mid, wheelOne_Bot;
int wheelTwo_Top, wheelTwo_Mid, wheelTwo_Bot;
int wheelThree_Top, wheelThree_Mid, wheelThree_Bot;
int coinsWon;

gameCoins = gameCoins-25;
wheelOne_Top = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelTwo_Top = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelThree_Top = (rand() % 3) + 1;
wheelOne_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelTwo_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelThree_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1;
wheelOne_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelTwo_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1, wheelThree_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1;

while (wheelOne_Top == wheelOne_Mid || wheelOne_Top == wheelOne_Bot || wheelOne_Bot == wheelOne_Mid)
{
    wheelOne_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    wheelOne_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1;
}
while (wheelTwo_Top == wheelTwo_Mid || wheelTwo_Top == wheelTwo_Bot || wheelTwo_Bot == wheelTwo_Mid)
{
    wheelTwo_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    wheelTwo_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1;
}
while (wheelThree_Top == wheelThree_Mid || wheelThree_Top == wheelThree_Bot || wheelThree_Bot == wheelThree_Mid)
{
    wheelThree_Mid = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    wheelThree_Bot = (rand() % 3) + 1;
}

cout << "Coins: " << gameCoins << endl << endl;
cout << "\t\t\t" << wheelOne_Top << " " << wheelTwo_Top << " " << wheelThree_Top << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\t" << wheelOne_Mid << " " << wheelTwo_Mid << " " << wheelThree_Mid << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\t" << wheelOne_Bot << " " << wheelTwo_Bot << " " << wheelThree_Bot << "\n\n";

coinsWon = getWinnings(wheelOne_Top, wheelOne_Mid);
gameCoins = coinsWon + gameCoins;

if (gameCoins > 0)
    cout << "You won " << gameCoins << " coins!" << "\n" << "Total Coins: " << gameCoins << "\n\n";
else
    cout << "You lost 25 coins!" << "\n" << "Total coins: " << gameCoins << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: When it says "This project has not been built yet, do you want to build it now?" You have to click "Yes".

Comment: I clicked yes and nothing. No errors, no program, just this in build log. Like I said, it will compile if i remove int b from the function getWinnings() but once I add more arguments I get nothing.                                           -------------- Build: Debug in Slot Machine (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\Slot Machine.exe" obj\Debug\main.o    
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds)

Comment: Then you have to run the program, hit F9 to do that.

Comment: I have compiled/ran programs before. That is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the last instance of the program is not still running. Check your task manager and force close Slot Machine.exe if you see it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the COMPILER acting funny, or it could be something about the ENVIRONMENT.

COMPILER:

If it's just some weird glitch with the compiler that causes it to crash (which would probably keep Code::Blocks from opening the executable and make it give you that message), then I recommend changing...

```
int getWinnings (int a,int b)
{
    return a + b;
};
```

...to `#define getWinnings(a,b) (a + b)`

ENVIRONMENT:

[I'm assuming you're using Windows.]

I get that notification sometimes, under two conditions.

The first is that I am accidentally hitting Build & Run on a header file that I was fixing, instead of on the actual program that I was using the test the header. In this case, if you gave the source file the wrong extension just close it, change the extension to ".c" or ".cpp" instead of ".h", and then reopen it.

The second is that Code::Blocks looked for the executable before Windows opened it to read access after the compiler closed the file after writing to it. In this case, after building it, if it gives you the message, just hit "No" and then hit the run button (not the Build & Run button).

If neither of these is the problem, you may have a problem with file access, such as that you are not on an Administrator-level account or that Code::Blocks hasn't been granted Administrator-level permissions. Try settings Code::Blocks to open with Administrator-level permissions (on Windows 7 that means you'll have to click the pop-up thing to allow it every time you open it), or if you can't do that then perhaps changing the directory you're compiling in.